# Why is jQuery's .preventDefault obscuring my animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, preventdefault

I had an anchor tag controlling some animation, with href set to javascript:void(); temporarily, and everything was working fine.  I changed the href to # and put event.preventDefault(); inside the function attached to anchor tag.  It's preventing the browser from going to #, **but now my animation doesn't happen, just a second later it shows the end point of the animation**.  I tried extending the duration of the animation by a second and then I see the end of the animation, so it's like the preventDefault is causing a hiccup for that first part.

Any idea what's going on here?  This is my code:

```
$('#galleryBelt .scrollRight a').click(function(event){
    slidepageCurr++;
    setScrollButtons();

    /* slide belt to the left */
    $('#galleryBelt ul').animate({
        left: '-='+slidepageWidth
    }, shiftDuration);

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does returning false help the situation?

```
$('#galleryBelt .scrollRight a').click(function(event){
    slidepageCurr++;
    setScrollButtons();

    /* slide belt to the left */
    $('#galleryBelt ul').animate({
        left: '-='+slidepageWidth
    }, shiftDuration);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Huh.  It... does.  How come that works?  Why does that make the browser ignore the href="#"?  Thank you, by the way.